# adding spring gem breaks tests - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, spring-gem

I have some test using rails `spec` (and also `capybara` and `factory girl`) and passing just fine

```
describe "project creation" do
  before(:each) do
    @project = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
  end
  it "create projects fluently" do
    visit root_path
    @project.should validate_presence_of(:title)
  end
end
```

Then I installed `spring`, and when I run `spring rspec spec/features/projects_spec.rb`, it throws

```
Failure/Error: @project.should validate_presence_of(:title)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup...
```

How can it be

Comment: Are you including the shoulda-matchers gem? validate_presence_of is a matcher from that gem...

Comment: @guilleva indeed I do not, because it is working fine when not using `spring`. Btw, I have just added this and it doesn't change anything !

Comment: spring preforks processes. this might cause issues when code get's reloaded. class variables and monkeypatching are especially sensistive to this kind of stuff. have a look at spring after_fork hook. that might help you in some kind of way. overall, it's hard to say without looking at the whole app. you need to find out where those methods come from and why the preforked process does not have them.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was discussed here: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/209, but in the readme file of shoulda-matchers gem say how install it with a preloader, basically my solution was:

1. Move the rspec-rails line in Gemfile above the shoulda-matchers
2. Add require: :false to shoulda-matchers in Gemfile
3. Add require 'shoulda/matchers' in spec_helper.rb

My Gemfile look like:

```
group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
  gem 'machinist'
end
```

Now my specs with shoulda helper work fine with spring!